# Handling of insert query such that if the table does not have a column mentioned in insert query

Tags: sql, db2

I have some automation scripts which insert data in database, now due to business requirement some column from the table is deleted and my automation script (SQL inset command) fails when it is not able to find the column. Is there any way possible to handle this type of problem.

So basically I was wondering if it was possible for handling of insert SQL query such that if the table does not have a column mentioned in insert query, the data in remaining columns are inserted and the query does not fail.

As an example, my insert query inserts values in column A, B, C, D. and due to change in business column D is removed from the table. Now is it possible that data is inserted in A, B, C and query does not fail.

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or DB2?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS of interest?

Comment: @Dale K It is DB2

Comment: @DheerajNagrani . . . At the very least, you would need to insert into a different table name.

Comment: The problem with this in the general case is that the system isn't going to know if such a column was "important" - to your `INSERT` statement or to something else you do later.  Which is why it explodes immediately.  It's not actually your automation script that failed, per se, rather it's more a communication or ownership failure from a management (project or otherwise) side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible.
Modify you script to construct such a query dynamically. For example, use the `syscat.columns` system view, if you are on Db2 for LUW.